# Insert into MySQL when POST form to Paypal

Tags: php, mysql, paypal

I've been struggling with this for hours and can't wrap my head around where/how to call a php function to insert order details into MySQL upon user clicking the Buy button (doing so at this point allows me to track orders that go to Paypal and then are abandoned).

I thought to put it in the `<form action=>` tag, (for example, `<form action='addToMySQL.php' method='post'>`) but that's where the Paypal url goes, yes? Function must be run server side, so can't use js... So... how to do this?

cURL has been suggested, and I've seen it recommended before, but would the user still be redirected to Paypal's payment page and then returned back to my site? Can anyone suggest a relevant web tutorial?

I'm new to web programming so details would be appreciated.

Function that creates the form to be sent to PayPal is:

```
function create_paypal_checkout {
return "
<form action='".PAYPAL_URL."' method='post'>
    <input type='hidden' name = 'business' value='".PAYPAL_ID."' />
    <input type='hidden' name = 'cmd' value='_cart' />
    <input type='hidden' name = 'upload' value='1' />
    <input type='hidden' name = 'currency_code' value='USD' />
    <input type='hidden' name = 'lc' value='US' />
    <input type='hidden' name='rm' value='2' />
    <input type='hidden' name='cancel_return' value='http://www.mydomain.com/'>
    <input type='hidden' name='notify_url' value='http://www.mydomain.com/ipn-listener.php'>
    <input type='hidden' name='return' value='http://www.mydomain.com/thankyou.php?custIP=".$custip."' />

    " . render_shopping_cart($shopping_cart) . "

<table class='formBuyButton'>
<tr id='sc_total'>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td id='ppbutt'>
        <input type='image' name='submit' src='https://www.paypalobjects.com/WEBSCR-640-20110306-1/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif' border='0' alt='PayPal - Buy Now' />
    </td>
</form></tr></table>" ;
}
```

Comment: What you want is a 'postback'. The form submits directly to Paypal, then Paypal connects to your server to pass in transaction details. What you're trying to do would not work without extra background processing to re-submit the data to Paypal via CURL.

Comment: I've got paypal's IPN system working correctly (all 4 comms) and also the thankyou.php landing page works and the returned $_POST values are parsed and mysql table is updated. However, these only action if the user completes the paypal transaction. I also wish to track orders that are never completed, so need to input to mysql upon initial submit to paypal. I'm not familiar with CURL - is that the way to go in this case then?

Comment: I don't know the details of the paypal checkout process, but basically you'd have to somehow post to your site first to capture the data, then redirect/re-post to paypal. How you do that is up to you. CURL's one way of doing an http request from one server to anothre, but isn't the only option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem and I solved it using ajax. What I do is to call a php script using ajax before submitting the form to Paypal. Here, I'm using the post function from jquery, since it easier. You need to have jquery somewhere and to point to it. When the user submit the form, mycall() is first called, and if it returns true, then the form it submitted to PayPal.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function mycall() {
        $.post('addToMySQL.php', {...}); // Replace ... with arguments
        return true;
    }
</script>

<form action='".PAYPAL_URL."' method='post' onSubmit='return mycall();'>
```

Comment: That looks like exactly what I want. Thank You. I'm new to all this: what exactly triggers the mycall() function? As soon as the view is generated, is the function running and listening for a POST event? I'm a little uncertain what the { ...arguments... } might look like: is it just a list of $vars separated by commas, as in {$custip, $numitems, $itemstring, $totalcost } ?

Comment: WHUPS, the trigger is obvious, I just missed it. I see now it's triggered in the form action: onSubmit='return mycall();' Perfect example with excellent detail; Thank You.

Comment: See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/ for details about post function. Be careful, it's Javascript, not php. The format is {name: value, name: value}. Use <?php echo $myvar; ?> as value if you need it from PHP.

Comment: Ah, you anticipated my error and prevented me making it. Thanks. I *was* going to list php variables as arguments. Perhaps I could save them into a cookie with php and read them out using js? (I'm pretty sure the <?php echo $myvar; ?> won't work in these circs since the html is being generated by a php function)